# How to decode an array contained in a dictionary directly using Swift JSON Decoder?

Tags: json, swift, nested, jsondecoder

Suppose we have a json object like this:

```
{
  "count": 2,
  "users": [
    {
      "name": "tom",
      "id": 123
    },
    {
      "name": "cat",
      "id": 456
    }
  ]
}
```

and the `User` struct would be like:

```
struct User: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let id: Int
}
```

Obviously you can create another struct named `Root` to decode the json object using `JSONDecoder`:

```
struct Root: Decodable {
    let count: Int,
    let users: [User]
}

let root = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: json)
let users = root.users
```

but actually `Root` is useless for me, the nested `users` is only what I concerned. So how can I decode only the `users` part into `[User]` without the needless `Root` struct?

Comment: You can use a custom `init(from decoder:)` to do so, but it's extra work. I'd keep rot, and just return `users`. or check https://github.com/aunnnn/NestedDecodable (didn't tested it)

Comment: Any other solution is probably more work than doing `let users = root.users`

Comment: @tomisacat `let users = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: json).users`. Btw no need to include the `count` property.

Comment: @LeoDabus Sure, but overall what I want is to remove needless `Root`

Comment: It is not needless. It is actually very useful.

Comment: When you rename it to a meaningful name like UserResponse, its utility is also more obvious. It is the decoding container for the response itself. That's useful, and a good place to hang functionality. Calling it Root makes it seem pointless when it's not.

Comment: @RobNapier It make sense, thanks : )